# Angular material sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I am following the [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io) documentation.
While building a side navbar i am getting the below error
"`'mat-nav-list' is not a known element:`"

I have imported the following

```
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
```

I tried other components by importing the APIs and all work fine except the sidenav

I really cannot figure out what went wrong.
Any suggestions will be great hep.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you are also not importing `MatListModule` from `@angular/material/list` in your app's module (or create a module dedicated for Material components):

`material.module.ts`:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule
  ],
  imports: [
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

`app.module.ts`:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks! MatListModule was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Importing it is not enough, you also need to add it to the same module that your component is defined in.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatSidenavModule
  ]
})
export class MyModule { }
```